# Page view to show nodes related through node reference

Tags: 7, nodes, views

I am working in Drupal 7 and I have two content types: "member charity" and "member news story." "member news story" contains a "field_charity_reference" field (a node reference) that creates a reference between the news story and the member charity the story is about. I wish to set up a view that shows all the news stories for any charity. I have set up a page view with the path /our-members/news/%. I can set a relationship on "Content: Charity Reference" that filters only nodes with a charity reference.

How do I pass the charity name from the URL, so that only "member news story" nodes with a node reference to the charity name are returned?

Note: I have tried using "content: NID" as a contextual filter, setting the relationship to "field_charity_reference" and "When the filter value is not in the url" set to provide a default value, type Raw value from URL, path component 3 and ticking "use path alias." I have also tried the above using "Content: Charity Reference," but neither of these return any results when I go to /our-members/news/example-charity-name.

Comment: which version of drupal?

Comment: Drupal 7 - Question amended

Comment: I don't think filtering by charity name is a good idea. Having nid in URL will be better even if charity name is somewhere in URL: /our-members/news/{NID}/example-charity-name

Comment: Hi Bulat. Could you explain why you don't think filtering by the charity name is a good idea? I am using pathauto to generate nice human readable path names and deliberately don't include NIDs as they are not meaningful to the end user. It would be unfortunate to revert to NIDs in the path name, but if you really think this is the way forward I would be interested to know your reasoning.

Comment: Hi Paul, it's not the only way forward, but it's just safer to have nid in URL. This way you know for sure that URL is uniquely resolvable. Let's see what publishers are doing - http://www.economist.com/news/finance-and-economics/21580494-private-company-controlled-banks-connects-much-financial; http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-22720228. URL should not be meaningful for end users, they actually will be more happy with something like this: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/22720228.

Comment: I can appreciate Bulat's points as to why having NID in URL can be preferable, however I am going to push on and try to resolve the issue with my established url system. I am part way there as I have realised that the problem with filtering on the node reference 'Charity Reference' was that it isn't expressed in the same format as the url slug. When I created a normal text field in the content type and filled it with 'example-charity-name' I was able to filter on this field and provide the raw value from URL as the default value. I will post an answer when this is resolved.